# How to have "RUN" command in docker-compose similar to dockerfile?

Tags: elasticsearch, plugins, docker, docker-compose

Docker file

```
FROM elasticsearch:2    
RUN /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/plugin install --batch cloud-aws
```

from https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-docker-plugin-management

Can someone plz help me to add ES plugin in docker-compose file?

```
version: '2'
services:
  nitrogen:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ~/mycode:/mycode
    depends_on:
      - couchdb
      - elasticsearch

elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:1.7.5
    volumes:
      - ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
```

In above docker-compose missing is installation of plugin.

Tried this but it runs on local machine, instead of docker container.

```
command: /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/plugin install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-river-couchdb/2.6.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create your own docker image like `my-elasticsearch` with the Dockerfile you mentioned, then in `docker-compose.yml` to refer to that image.